# Language selector in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Lets say i want to color all words that  begin  the language attribute with ***en***. How i have done it so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
[lang|=en] {
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p lang="en">This is English!</p>
<p lang="en-us">This is English and US!</p>
<p lang="en-gb">English here too!</p>
<p lang="us">US is not English!</p>
<p lang="no">Definitely not English !</p>


</body>
</html>
```

How can i access all elements whose lang attribute value is ***en***
**without the usage of [attribute|=value] selector or the lang()** pseudo class. Is there a way?

Answer (score 6):

The :lang() pseudo (and, arguably, to a lesser extent the attribute selector) was made specifically for this purpose. You can't expect to match elements based on their locale if you don't use :lang().

Comment: I haven't checked so I ask is `p[lang^="en-"]` not possible ?

Comment: can't we somehow do it with the nth-child or first of type selectors? There has to be a way...

Comment: @Pogrindis: It is if your lang attribute is guaranteed to start with en-. It won't match [lang=en] elements of course. But I don't see why the OP has to avoid those two selectors specifically.

Comment: @Aggelos Sfakianos: What makes you think that you can use :nth-child to match elements based on their locale?